# Unable to access Rest URL using scalaj-Http client with SSL certificates(JKS File)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sap-bw, scalaj-http

I am new to Scala.  I am trying to access REST API URl and trying to get json data from there using Scalaj-Http with Spark framework in local vm(Intellij). But with the following Code I am always getting Http error code 401 from code and the server log is responding with "new ssl session,TLS V1.2 No Client Cert.

The jks file that I am using seems ok with proper SSL Handshake and its installed on server side.

```
val url = "https://abcdef:1234/api/v1/get?q=abc"
val alias ="xxxxxx-1234 yyyyy"
val sslFactory = SSLFactory.builder()
.withIdentityMaterial("abc.jks","pass".tocharArray)
.withTrustMaterial("abc.jks","pass".tocharArray)
.withClientIdentityRoute(alias,url)
.build()

val optn = HttpOptions.sslSocketFactory(sslfactory.getSslSocketfactory)

val res = Http(url) //Here getting 401 res.code
.option(optn)
.option(HttpOptions.allowUnsafeURL)
.asString
```

Tried everything but unable to solve. Kindly help please

Answer (score 1):

I got the code working as I have to discard this option option(HttpOptions.allowUnsafe
URL)

Thanks